# Проблемы с вычитанием в Powershell

Tags: powershell

Казалось бы простая операция, вычитание, вызывает проблемы в PowerShell. 
Кто может объяснить, почему:

3.1 - 3 = 0,1

4.1 - 4 = 0,0999999999999996

20.1 - 20 = 0,100000000000001

Не хотелось бы прикручивать округление, в такой простой операции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Храните числа в `decimal`. Вот так:

```
PS C:\> [decimal]3.1 - 3
0.1
PS C:\> [decimal]4.1 - 4
0.1
PS C:\> [decimal]20.1 - 20
0.1
```

Описанная вами проблема - обычное явление для чисел с плавающей запятой.

Comment: Первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой, спасибо